# How to return simple data with json

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, jquery-mobile

How do I return the following json data in a succesfull array:

```
    [{"Identifier":1,"Naam":"NOT Given","Adres":"Kopenhagen 9","Postcode":"0000LL","Plaats":"NOT Given","Longitude":"0.00000","Latitude":"0.00000"},
{"Identifier":2,"Naam":"NOT Given","Adres":"NOT Given 1","Postcode":"0000LL","Plaats":"Rotterdam","Longitude":"0.00000","Latitude":"0.00000"},
{"Identifier":3,"Naam":"NOT Given","Adres":"NOT Given 6","Postcode":"0000LL","Plaats":"Rotterdam","Longitude":"0.00000","Latitude":"0.00000"},
{"Identifier":4,"Naam":"NOT Given","Adres":"NOT Given 1","Postcode":"0000LL","Plaats":"Den Haag","Longitude":"0.00000","Latitude":"0.00000"},
{"Identifier":5,"Naam":"NOT Given","Adres":"NOT Given 218","Postcode":"0000LL","Plaats":"Zoetermeer","Longitude":"0.00000","Latitude":"0.00000"}]
```

I want to get this in an array an call for example data.Naam where id = 2.

If u use this code:

```
$.post( "http://notGiven", {}, function(data) { 
        alert('Aantal elementen in lijst: ' + data.length); 
        $.each(data, function(index, element) {

            });
        });
```

then data length gives me a number above 3000 why that.

And if i try element.Naam in the loop then it returns undefined...

So.. How do i get the data which my json returns, like all the names?? without showing undefined errors...

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're trying to achieve, but `.length` will return the number of first-generation definitions in the object. If it says 3000, that's how many there are.

Comment: but if i do like element.Naam it returns undefined..

Comment: but do you know the anwser to my question @Utkanos?

Comment: Can you set up a JS Bin to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: i made it a bit different but the complete idea is the same http://jsbin.com/equkaf/1/edit @Utkanos

Comment: Well the `$.post` request wasn't going anywhere, so the callback never fired. I've tweaked it slightly. Now you have output from your data. http://jsbin.com/equkaf/6/edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @Utkanos said,

the solution is here: http://jsbin.com/equkaf/6/edit